# Can't load an entire new google map with jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have a Google map on my page and a toggle switch button. When the toggle gets clicked I have it call a java script function that clears the div element that has the current google map and loads another one in:

```
//clear div
        $('#putMap').empty();

        //call to get new friend list
        $('#putMap').load('getVisitMap.php?u=' + userID ,
            function() {
            alert("called load function");
        }); 

        return false;
```

My get visit php file looks like this:

```
$userID = $_GET['u'];
    //Get all breweries

    echo "<div id=\"map_canvas\" style=\"width: 600px; height: 400px;\"></div>";


    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    var locations = [';

    //count unique breweries
    ***mysql call is here****

    echo "before for loop";

    for( $i = 0; $i < $breweryNum; $i++){
        $row = $resultBrew ->fetch_assoc();
        $brewery = $row['beerBrewery'];
        $long = $row['longi'];
        $lat = $row['lat'];

        $breweryURL = "breweryPage.php?id=$breweryID";


        echo "['$brewery', $lat, $long] ";

        //add camas if not last one
        if($i !=  $breweryNum - 1 ){
            echo   ',';

        }

    }

        echo ' 

        ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(\'map_canvas\'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });


        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]);  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map
      });



      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, \'click\', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));

      bounds.extend(position);

    } //end for loop


    map.fitBounds(bounds);


  </script>

        ';
```

Also when I look in inspect element in chrome under network to see the response for getVisitMap.php file It only showes this:

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div><script type="text/javascript">
    var locations = [
```

my echos I have should show a lot more code.

Here is some more code of the original php page:

```
$page->content .= "<div id = \"putMap\">
<div id=\"map_canvas\" style=\"width: 600px; height: 400px;\"></div>";  
$map = createMap($userID);


$page->content .= "

$map
</div>
";
```

Comment: is put `#putMap` your map canvas? because if so you need to set it to `.setMap(null)` before re-invoking the map.

Comment: @DavidChase I added some more code which may answer that question